# Install4j Not Removing from Apps and Features

Tags: install4j

I installed a JavaFX app with a bundled JRE with Install4j.  The installation works fine and starts the app. However, when I uninstall from the Windows 10 Apps & Features screen's Uninstall button, the deployment directory and start menu item are removed but the item on the screen is not.  That item is removed if I run the uninstall.exe directly from the deployment directory.

I verified that the app was not running when I attempted to use the Uninstall button.

Is there a property I should set to make sure that the item clears?

Thank you

Comment: You mean the item in the Windows 10 Apps & Features screen? In both cases the uninstaller is invoked. The entry in the Windows 10 Apps & Features screen consists of a few registry entries that are removed by the uninstaller. When you close and open the screen, is it cleared then?

Comment: No, it remains with the Uninstall button disabled when I run from Apps & Features.  Running the uninstaller.exe directly from the install folder does remove the item though.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with the "hello" sample project?

Comment: No, the hello sample (installed with the service) worked for me.  In my app, I'm installing in the user's home.  The hello sample was installed as admin under Program Files.

Comment: Could you send your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com so I can try to reproduce something similar?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. File sent to support.  I'll post an update for everyone else when I hear back.

Comment: I created a new project and am having the same problems uninstalling.  I noticed there is a different structure to the uninstall tasks and settings from the plain project that I created.  I tried reconciling them but still can't get the Add/Remote Item to uninstall.